# select statement blocking another select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not quite sure what is happening here.  I have an alert that goes out if `@StoreOrderID >1`.

It goes like this:

```
declare @message varchar(1000)
@StoreID --(retrieves info from StoreOrders tables)

BEGIN
    select @message =  'store' + storename 
                                from StoreOrders as so
                                join Distributors as ds
                                on ds.DistributorID = so.StoreOrderID
                                where ds.SDistributorID = @StoreID


    select @message =   brandID
                                from StoreOrders a 
                                join Brandtitles as b
                                on b.branddistributorID = a.StoreOrderID
                                where b.brandNum = @DistributorNum and b.branddistributorID = @StoreID

select @message = 'date' + ISNULL(convert(varchar, @Date),'') 
select @message = 'cost' + ISNULL(Convert(varchar,@Cost),'')
```

Also for some reason if i try to concatenate a string unto the 'brand' select it throws an error.  I can do it for the 'storename'. I think this may have something to do with it.

If I comment out the storename `select` it will send the alert for `brandID`, if I comment out the other one it does the other one. However, if I leave both of them, it will only show one of them.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The second SELECT over-writes the first SELECT (@message), so the first SELECT works, but then the value is thrown away when the second one over-writes it.

Comment: But I have about three other select statements beneath it that all get sent as an alert.

Comment: Well, you're not showing those so I can't see them. I can only tell you that with both of these SELECTs in that order, you're over-writing the value of 'message' from the first one with the second one, so if you do something afterwards, you're only going to see the second one. You don't really have enough info in this question to diagnose further. But clearly you can't expect 'message' to have BOTH values simultaneously. That's not how variables work.

Comment: What do you mean by "get sent as an alert"? You have a variable. Then you assign it a value. And then immediately assign it a new value. Why are you confused that it will ALWAYS have the second value?

Answer (score 1):

As a user mentioned in the comments, you are overwriting the  `@message` variable everytime you assign it a new value, you are not concatenating any of the values. A much simpler and cleaner way would be something like....

```
declare @message varchar(1000)
        @StoreID [DataType]--(retrieves info from StoreOrders tables)


BEGIN

Declare  @storename  VARCHAR(100)
       , @brandID    VARCHAR(100)
       , @Date       VARCHAR(100)
       , @Cost       VARCHAR(100);

    select @storename =  'store' + ISNULL(storename , 'Unknown') 
    from StoreOrders as so
    join Distributors as ds
    on ds.DistributorID = so.StoreOrderID
    where ds.SDistributorID = @StoreID;


    select @brandID =   ISNULL(CAST( brandID AS VARCHAR(100) , 'Unknown')
    from StoreOrders a 
    join Brandtitles as b
    on b.branddistributorID = a.StoreOrderID
    where b.brandNum = @DistributorNum 
      and b.branddistributorID = @StoreID;

select @Date = 'date' + ISNULL(convert(varchar, @Date),'');
select @Cost = 'cost' + ISNULL(Convert(varchar,@Cost),'');

SET @message = @storename + @brandID + @Date + @Cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Assume the code "alerting" the message is after the snipped you showed.

Then, as you use the same variable `@message` as target for both assignments, you overwrite the contents you assigned the first time when doing the second assignment. Only the values from the second assignment make it to the "alerting" command.

Use two different variables or "alert" your message after each assignment.